# Why does __LASTFOCUS hidden field show up on only some ASP.Net pages?

Tags: asp.net, focus, postback

I'd been using the hookonfocus method from this article: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MainatinFocusASPNET.aspx

to maintain focus during postbacks for certain .aspx pages.  However, I've noticed that several pages (and some very simple pages in a test project) don't include the hidden field __LASTFOCUS.  I'm trying to figure out which options I'm missing that will cause this hidden field to show up and be used to restore focus if I use javascript to keep __LASTFOCUS up to date when focus changes happen in an ASPX page.

Note: I'm using VS 2005/.Net 2.0 in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__LASTFOCUS` field is created by `Page.RegisterFocusScript()`, which is called from...

- [ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference(PostBackOptions, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223392%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) if [PostBackOptions.TrackFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.postbackoptions.trackfocus%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is set.
- [Page.SetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.setfocus%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
- [BaseValidator.Validate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validate%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) (via `Page.SetValidatorInvalidControlFocus`) to focus controls that fails validation

It is also called in the OnPreRender method of CheckBox, ListControl and TextBox (and any derivatives). I'm guessing that the pages that does not output the `__LASTFOCUS` field does not contain any variant of these three controls.

Comment: Awesome!  I put Page.SetFocus() in a test master page and immeditately the field shows up like I expect.  (Of course, it's not being used automatically like it was on my other pages, ie: focus isn't being set based on it, I have to do that manually for some reason still.)

Comment: I'm doing this based on the answer, but feel like I'm still missing something:
        `this.Page.SetFocus(Request.Form["__LASTFOCUS"] ?? this.Page.ID);`